# Switch regions on EB CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

The only way I know how to switch regions using the EB CLI is `eb init`. This feels like a hack because in addition to selection my region, I have to re-answer a bunch of questions I've already answered.

Is there a way to just switch regions on the EB CLI without going through all the `eb init` steps?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. When you run `eb init` it should only ask you for the things it doesn't know. Running it a second time should do nothing. Therefore I am presuming you are running `eb init -i` which forces all the questions.
You can simply use `eb init --region us-east-1` to switch. It shouldn't ask you any questions.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for. Just a small correction: it needs to be `us-east-1` as opposed to `us-east1`.

Answer (score 4):

When you run `eb init`, the EB CLI will generate `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` file inside working directory. The file format is something like:

```
branch-defaults:
  default:
    environment: Sample-Env
global:
  application_name: Example App
  default_ec2_keyname: SecretSSH-Key
  default_platform: 64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v2.0.0 running Docker 1.6.2
  default_region: us-east-1
  profile: null
  sc: null
```

You can modify `default_region` to another valid region.